# Passing array of Parcelable using Intent.putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I have created a Parcelable class called Song and am trying to pass an array of them between activities using Intent.putExtra() currently once i get to the activity and use this.intent.getParcelableArrayExtra i get an array of parcelable and I cant find a way to convert it back to an array of Songs.

code starting activity:

```
val i = Intent(this, CompletedSongsActivity::class.java)
val completedSongs = songList.filter{ it.solved }.toTypedArray()
i.putExtra("COMPLETED_SONGS", completedSongs)
startActivity(i)
```

code in activity:

```
val songs = this.intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("COMPLETED_SONGS") as Array<Song>
```

I then get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to com.example.kyle.songle.Song[]
```

EDIT:

my Song class:

```
class Song(val name: String,val artist: String,val youtubeURL: String,val number: Int, var solved: Boolean): Parcelable {

companion object {
    @JvmField @Suppress("unused")
    val CREATOR = object: Parcelable.Creator<Song> {
        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Song?> {
            return arrayOfNulls<Song>(size)
        }

        override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel?): Song {
            return Song(source!!)
        }
}}

private constructor(parcelIn: Parcel) : this(parcelIn.readString(),parcelIn.readString(),parcelIn.readString(),0,true)

override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
    dest?.writeString(name)
    dest?.writeString(artist)
    dest?.writeString(youtubeURL)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Show your `Song` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to directly convert the array as you are trying to do.
The return value of `getParcelableArrayExtra("COMPLETED_SONGS")` as far as android's OS is concerned is an array of `Parcelable` that just happens to contain just `Song` instances.

To use it directly you can use the [`Array.filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html) function to create `List<Song>` that is guaranteed to be type-safe. If it absolutely needs to be an array then `.toTypedArray()` will convert it back to `Array<Song>`

This should result in the following code: `val songs = getParcelableArrayExtra("COMPLETED_SONGS").filterIsInstance<Song>().toTypedArray()`

Comment: Could you give a code example of using either of these solutions?

Comment: you say if it absolutely needs to be an array, is there a better way of passing a list/array or other collection of objects between activities?